# Is it possible to have different child views for an ExpandableListView in android based on a value from the parent adapter?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In the app I'm working on, I currently use a button to open a new activity that has a simple filterable listview in it.  When the user clicks on a row in the listview, the selected value is returned back to the previous Activity to then have something done with it.  This means I have two activities to do one function.

I was looking for a way to combine the two elegantly, and think that an expandablelistview is the way to go, but I'm not sure about one thing:  Can the getChildView be overridden (custom expandablelistview) to inflate a different view based on a value in the parent group adapter?

My adapter selects two values from an sqlite database,  an integer called "Type" and a String called "Move".  I only show the "Move", but bind the "Type" to an TextView that's hidden.   If I implement a single expandablelistview, I would need to somehow pass the "Type" to the drop down, so that it could display a different child view (allowing user to enter either weight, time, or reps, based on a type value of "1", "2", or "3".

Is this possible with a custom ELV that overrides the getchildview method? I see that you can get the parent position, and the child position, but besides using a global variable when the parent is clicked, I can't see anything that is passed to the child to know the value, text, etc that was the parent?

I found a nice implementation as well here: https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

But it seems too complex to try and override that, so I'm just going to try a standard Expandable List View if it's possible.

Thankss!

Edit: Here's a bad mockup of what I'm talking about.  First drop would have a view with just a box and a button,  second view might have a box and a button, but third view has two boxes, one for weight, one for reps, and then a button.:

[image]

Comment: Your setup is not clear and you may want to add details about the interaction you plan. From what I understood you want(to inflate a special layout for the child views(all of them?) based on a parameter(type) present in the group's data), it's possible(but by extending the adapter not the widget itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that is to create one View Layout for all possible types you want to show in one item of the ExpandableListView.

You just override the Adapters `getChildView` and select Type and Move in their. Then you set the parts of your View to `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to ensure, the right kind of View is shown.

Comment: I just posted a quick mockup in fluidui.com of what I'm trying to talk about.  If there is only  only one field, the rows can probably stay the same, but if i need two or more entries (weight and time, weight and reps, etc) then a different layout would need to show.  

So if I override the getchildview, I can pass additional data items to the constructor (getChildView)?

Comment: I see what you mean. I would create a layout for the item, that contains the maximum complexity, one item can have. In your case two boxes and a button. Then, in `getChildView()`, you decide which part of the item should be shown (`View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`) and what parts should not be shown (completely gone, not only invisible:  `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)`)

Comment: Awesome, I'l have to give it a shot this week, if that works I'll accept your initial answer.  Thanks!